# Prove $(G,.)$ group.

Tags: group-theory

If

$$G = \left\{ 
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\
b & a \end{pmatrix} a,b\in \mathbb{R} : a,b \neq 0
\right\} $$

Prove that $(G,.)$ group.

I proved binary operation and associative , but what about identity and Inverse?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did it go wrong? Also, what is the operation? Matrix multiplication?

Comment: I don't speak English well, I don't understand your first question, but for second question yes.

Comment: If . implies multiplication, we have to make sure that the matrix is invertible.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget to place a minus sign on one of the $b$'s in the matrix? because if you put one on say the $b$ of row 1 it would be a group isomorphic to the nonzero complex numbers under multiplication, And your condition shoud be really $a^2+b^2 \neq 0$ or put another way $a,b$ are not *both* zero,

Answer (score 5):

The identity, as is the case with many matrix-based groups, is simply the $2 \times 2$
identity matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0 \\ 0&1\end{array}\right).$$
We can see that
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} a&b \\ c&d \end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0 \\ 0&1\end{array}\right)
=\left(\begin{array}{cc} a&b \\ c&d \end{array}\right)
= \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0 \\ 0&1\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc} a&b \\ c&d \end{array}\right).$$

In terms of inverse, consider the matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} \frac{d}{ad-bc}&\frac{-b}{ad-bc}
\\ \frac{-c}{ad-bc}& \frac{a}{ad-bc}\end{array}\right).$$

You can check with a simple calculation that this is the inverse of
$\left(\begin{array}{cc} a&b \\ c&d\end{array}\right),$ assuming
$a$ and $b$ are not equal to $0$.

Comment: But what one needs for existence of the inverse is really $ad-bc \neq 0.$

Answer (score 3):

This is not a group. While we can see that $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1& 0 \\ 0 &1\end{array}\right) \in G$.

$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1& 1 \\ 1 &1\end{array}\right) \in G$ does not have an inverse as it is singular